# Display Attributes from Core Data ManagedObjectContext

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, core-data, swift

I'm learning Core Data with Swift and I want to see what is currently saved in my ManagedObjectContext. The viewDidLoad() includes `println(managedObjectContext!)` which outputs something like `<NSManagedObjectContext: 0x1701f8500>` to the console.

How do I see what the actual attributes of my LogItem are?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Managed objects are not being saved *in* `NSManagedObjectContext`. They are saved in a persistent store (like SQLite database). `NSManagedObjectContext` is used for loading managed objects from the persistent store into memory and making changes to them. Then you either save the changes back to the persistent store or discard them.

If you want to load managed objects (instances of an entity called `YourEntity`) from the persistent store into NSManagedObjectContext, use `NSFetchRequest`:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "YourEntity")
if let fetchResults = managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) {
    println(fetchResults);
}
```

If you want to see the objects that are currently loaded into NSManagedObjectContext, you can use `registeredObjects` method. If you want to see only updated / inserted / deleted objects, there are methods for that, called: `updatedObjects`, `insertedObjects`, `deletedObjects`.

Answer (score 3):

`_NSManagedObjectContext_` manages the `_NSManagedObjects_` by actually loading those objects into the memory under the same context. So if you want to display the content what your object model holds then you can access the `_registeredObjects_` property of managedObjectContext. But remember that it will enlist only/all those objects which has been loaded to context.

```
println(managedObjectContext!.registeredObjects);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can see a managed object context as a workbench on which you work with your model objects. You load them, you manipulate them, and save them on that workbench. Loading and saving are mediated by the persistent store coordinator.

```
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Entity")
    if let fetchResults = managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as?       [Entity] {            
         for info in fetchResults {
         println(info.valueForKey("attribute"));
        }
     }
```